# how do I replace the JSON serializer codec in grails?

Tags: json, grails, jackson

The grails built in JSON object is not cutting the mustard in the CPU usage department.

Jackson does a much better job, however I like the way grails has "as JSON" syntax set up.

Is there a way for me to configure grails to replace the default JSON implementation to be something I build myself (eg, a Jackon wrapper)?

Comment: I just realised the title should be deserializer rather than serializer.  My specific scenario has to do with HttpBuilder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of couse, JSON is just the class `grails.converters.JSON`. So Basically, you could import your own `myapp.converters.JSON`

```
import myapp.conv.JSON

def blabla() {
   render [bla:bla, [blou:blou]] as JSON
}
```

Comment: That works for cases where I am doing the conversion myself, however in cases such as HTTPBuilder making web service requests I seem to be unable to supply it with an alternative parser to use.

Answer (score 0):

moskiteau's answer is correct for the way I worded the question.

For the use case I had, I needed to look at HttpBuilder.parsers